# HDD neither mounted or umountable

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a hdd that is acting strangely. This is a fresh reboot:

```
greg@GSJ:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb ~/hdd
mount: /dev/sdb already mounted or /home/greg/hdd busy
```

OK, it's already mounted. I'll just `umount` that ...

```
greg@GSJ:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdb
umount: /dev/sdb: not mounted
```

What?

So tried e2fsck for good luck. No joy.

```
greg@GSJ:~$ sudo e2fsck /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
e2fsck: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sdb
Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program?
```

I'm using ubuntu. Is there any advice on what I can do from here?

Comment: what happens if you create a fresh mountpoint and mount /dev/sdb there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you are trying to mount a device and not a partition. `/dev/sda` is your primary master drive. It will have various partitions (`/sda1`,`sda2` etc) and *those* can be mounted but not the device itself.

To see the available partitions run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`, then try and mount whichever one it is you actually wanted to mount. For example, on my system:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda foo/
mount: /dev/sda already mounted or foo/ busy
$ sudo umount /dev/sda
umount: /dev/sda: not mounted
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 foo/    <== works
$ sudo umount /dev/sda1        <== works
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely a tool like fsck is running in the background on that partition.

Examine the output of lsof

> lsof /dev/sda1

Comment: Welcome on SU(here!). The use of `lsof` is a useful suggestion to understand which process is using the partition. It's not needed that fsck is running, it's enough that the partition is mounted. Usually on `/dev/sda1`, if there is not Windows, there is the root partition (or the whole one), so it is high the probability that someone is using it :-) The op problem is compatible with the [answer of  terdon](http://superuser.com/a/588767/257269) that the op accepted.